# How to create ipa without Apple Developer Programmer in Xcode 8?

Tags: ipa, xcode8

How to create ipa without Apple Developer Programmer in Xcode 8?

I found post in Xcode 7 but it does not work.

Comment: > "I found post in Xcode 7 but it does not work." -- can you share what you found?

Comment: dosn't work but will search and share it